# Массив не записывается

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Как заставить это работать? Массив не записывается и выдает пустой массив

```
const address = fetch("https://api.yoonost.com/account/session")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => {
        return response;
    })

const PrivateOutlet = () => {
    let response = { }

    address.then((a) => {
        response = a
    });

    console.log(response)

    return <Outlet />
}
```

Comment: Он и не может записаться. Последний `console.log(response)` сработает раньше чем `address.then(...)`. Все должно быть через асинхронные функции.

Comment: Раз уже дело зашло за реакт, то Вам как минимум надо `useEffect()`